# I failed to connect AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance and when I try to connect, I fail with the message like the below.

```
failed to connect to your instance ec2 instance connect is unable to connect to your instance. ensure your instance network settings are configured correctly for ec2 instance connect. for more information, see set up ec2 instance connect at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsec2/latest/userguide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html.
```

I tried to connect by SSH using, PuTTy but it didn't work and I can't reach my website hosted on the instance as well.

This was not a new instance and it was working fine.

Comment: Did you check the instance status and the system log in the EC2 console?

Comment: Since the instance previously worked but no does not work, have you tried **Rebooting** the instance?

Answer (score 0):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)